# Doctrine/symfony : creating 2 many-to-many relations(2 intermediate tables) on the SAME two tables

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

in my very "rare" case, i must create 2 many-to-many relations on the same tables.
I explain:
I have a two tables ; Monitor and Server having many to many rel the intermediate table will be called "Benchmark". But in the same time i have to have another intermediate table which can allow me to couple a url from a monitor to several ip's from the servers (the table is called "Url_ip")
So here is what i've done :

```
    Monitor:
      tableName: monitor
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        id : {type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true}
        label: {type: string(45)}
        url: {type: string(80)}
        frequency: {type: integer}
        timeout: {type: integer}
        method: {type: enum, values: [GET, POST]}
        parameters: {type: string(255)}
      relations:
        Groups:
          class: Groups
          local: monitor_id
          foreign: sf_guard_group_id
          refClass: Alert
        Server:
          class: Server
          local: monitor_id
          foreign: server_id
          refClass: Benchmark
        Server2:
          class: Server
          local: monitor_id
          foreign: server_id
          foreignAlias: Ips
          refClass: Url_ip

    Url_ip:
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        monitor_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
        server_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
      relations:
        Monitor:
          foreignAlias: IpUrls
        Server:
          foreignAlias: IpUrls       

    Benchmark:
      tableName: benchmark
      actAs:
        Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        monitor_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
        server_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
        connexionTime: {type: string(45)}
        executionTime: {type: string(45)}
        responseTime: {type: string(45)}
        responseCode: {type: string(45)}
        responseMessage: {type: string(45)}
      relations:
        Monitor:
          foreignAlias: ServerMonitors
        Server:
          foreignAlias: ServerMonitors



    Server:
      tableName: server
      actAs:
        TimeStampable: ~
      columns:
        id : {type: integer(4), primary: true,autoincrement: true}
        name: {type: string(255)}
        ip: {type: string(45)}
      relations:
        Monitor:
          class: Monitor
          local: server_id
          foreign: monitor_id
          refClass: Benchmark
        Monitor2:
          class: Monitor
          foreignAlias: monitors
          local: server_id
          foreign: monitor_id
          refClass: Url_ip


Alert:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    monitor_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true }
    sf_guard_group_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Monitor:
      foreignAlias: GroupMonitors
    sfGuardGroup:
      foreignAlias: GroupMonitors
```

Actually this appears to work because doctrine can create corresponding tables.
The problem is when loading the fixures. i have this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a c
hild row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sfmonitoring`.`alert`, CONSTRAINT `al
ert_monitor_id_monitor_id` FOREIGN KEY (`monitor_id`) REFERENCES `monitor` (`id`
))
```

fixures/monitors.yml

```
Monitor:
  monitor_one:
    id: 1
    label: task1
    url: www.task1.com
    frequency: 5
    timeout: 30
    method: GET
    parameters: a=1&b=2

  monitor_two:
    id: 2
    label: task2
    url: www.task2.com
    frequency: 5
    timeout: 20
    method: POST
    parameters: a=11&b=22

  monitor_three:
    id: 3
    label: task3
    url: www.task3.com
    frequency: 10
    timeout: 30
    method: GET
    parameters: a=111&b=211
```

fixures/benchmark.yml

```
Benchmark: 
      bench_one:
        monitor_id: 1
        server_id: 1
        connexionTime: 25
        executionTime: 25
        responseTime: 25
        responseCode: 200
        responseMessage: message de réponse

      bench_two:
        monitor_id: 2
        server_id: 2
        connexionTime: 25
        executionTime: 25
        responseTime: 25
        responseCode: 200
        responseMessage: message de réponse

      bench_three:
        monitor_id: 3
        server_id: 3
        connexionTime: 25
        executionTime: 25
        responseTime: 25
        responseCode: 200
        responseMessage: message de réponse

      bench_Four:
        monitor_id: 1
        server_id: 2
        connexionTime: 25
        executionTime: 25
        responseTime: 25
        responseCode: 200
        responseMessage: message de réponse
```

fixures/alerts.yml

```
Alert:
  alert_a:
    monitor_id: 1
    sf_guard_group_id: 1

  alert_b:
    monitor_id: 2
    sf_guard_group_id: 2Alert:
  alert_a:
    monitor_id: 1
    sf_guard_group_id: 1

  alert_b:
    monitor_id: 2
    sf_guard_group_id: 2
```

HELP ---------> S.O.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `Alert` model look like? (Is that the `Url_ip`?)

And it's better to reference models by their key instead of their ID.

```
Monitor:
  monitor1:
    ....

Alert:
  alert_a:
    Monitor: monitor1
    Group: group1
```

Because the error you're getting now, means that your adding an `Alert` with a reference to a non-existing monitor. This could happen when the `Alert` is inserted before the `Monitor`. By referencing to the `Monitor` by key instead of id, symfony will insert the `Monitor` first.

Comment: i've modified my question and added the Alert structure. please Read it

Comment: i did this :alert_a:
    Monitor: monitor_one
    Groups: Group_admin

Comment: but i have this error :
  Class referred to in "(alert) alert_a" is expected to be "Groups" and "sfGuard
Group" was given

Comment: i use the sfGuard own fixture

Answer (score 0):

That's it, i found a small trick!
 in fact in monitor, i did like you said : used the key !
but in the Group i processed normally, but using the sfGuard's id, and not mine !

```
Alert:
  alert_a:
    Monitor: monitor1
    sf_guard_group: group1
```